# Return JSON as an associative object?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Postgres 11 and have the following SQL:

```
SELECT json_agg("Result"."record")
FROM (SELECT jsonb_build_object('emailAddress', "User"."emailAddress", 'displayName', "User"."displayName") as "record"
      FROM "User")
"Result"
```

and it returns a single row like follows:

```
[
  {"displayName": "Keith Stephens", "emailAddress": "kstephensqv@goo.gl"},
  {"displayName": "Robert Armstrong", "emailAddress": "rarmstrongrf@gooogle.es"}, 
  {"displayName": "Aaron Wagner", "emailAddress": "awagnerrh@cambo.ac.uk"}
]
```

What I'd like though is the result as an associative object:

```
{
  "kstephensqv@goo.gl": {"displayName": "Keith Stephens", "emailAddress": "kstephensqv@goo.gl"},
  "rarmstrongrf@gooogle.es": {"displayName": "Robert Armstrong", "emailAddress": "rarmstrongrf@gooogle.es"}, 
  "awagnerrh@cambo.ac.uk": {"displayName": "Aaron Wagner", "emailAddress": "awagnerrh@cambo.ac.uk"}
}
```

Is there any way I can get the desired result using just a Postgres SQL expression?

Answer (score 0):

So after posting this question I immediately had a thought and came up with this which seems to do what I want:

```
SELECT json_object_agg("Result"."key", "Result"."record")
FROM (SELECT "User"."emailAddress" as "key", jsonb_build_object('emailAddress', "User"."emailAddress", 'displayName', "User"."displayName") as "record"
      FROM "User") "Result"
```